# How to approach a LP problem with Upper bounds

Tags: linear-programming, change-of-variable, operations-research, simplex-method

I need to solve the following problem:
$$\max: x_1+12x_2+65x_3; $$
$$x_2+4x_3 \leq 200;$$
$$x_1+10x_2+60x_3 \leq 750; $$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3 \leq 50 $$
To solve it efficiently by hand, I have tried to make the following change of variable:
$y_i=50 - x_i \ge 0$ for $i = 1,2,3$
So the problem I have to solve is:
$$\max: y_1+12y_2+65y_3-3900;$$
$$y_2+4y_3 \geq 50;$$
$$y_1+10y_2+60y_3 \geq 2800;$$
And the solution is unbounded, which doesn't make sense.
**My question is, what's wrong with the change of variable?, and how do you properly do it?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you replace $x_i$ with $50-y_i$ in the objective function, you will get $-1$ times the expression that you reported.  You have also omitted the lower bounds $y_i \ge 0$ that result from the upper bounds $x_i \le 50$.

Comment: That's true, but the solution still doesn't make sense. The computer gives me $(2050,0, 12.5)$.

Comment: Note what Rob said about your objective function (when converted from $x$ to $y$). As stated, it is wrong.